# How do I get an element that is nested within a JSON dictionary?

Tags: json, django, dictionary, python-requests, element

I got a JSON response using the Spotify API and I'm trying to access the element called 'name' (one says '3 Doors Down' and the other starts with 'Bret Michaels') that seems to be inside the 'items' element but I can't seem to find the solution.

This is how I loaded the data:

```
search_results = requests.get(search_url + 'q=' + query + '&type=artist', headers=granted_headers).json()
```

Here is my JSON data:

```
{
  'artists': {
    'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=3+doors+down&type=artist&offset=0&limit=20',
    'items': [
      {
       'external_urls': {
       'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/2RTUTCvo6onsAnheUk3aL9'
      },
      'followers': {
      'href': None,
      'total': 2631330
      },
      'genres': [
        'alternative metal',
        'nu metal',
        'pop rock',
        'post-grunge'
      ],
      'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/2RTUTCvo6onsAnheUk3aL9',
      'id': '2RTUTCvo6onsAnheUk3aL9',
      'images': [
        {
          'height': 640,
          'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ead4e883a59d30d8c157385aa531d3fe8e688fc0',
          'width': 640
        },
        {
          'height': 320,
          'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/611a4fd8aaf2637c5894acf65f12e79d75926329',
          'width': 320
        },
        {
          'height': 160,
          'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/f1a1a2c37f2f6d242b1ab7ae3f4d893bf5822095',
          'width': 160
        }
      ],
      'name': '3 Doors Down',
      'popularity': 72,
      'type': 'artist',
      'uri': 'spotify:artist:2RTUTCvo6onsAnheUk3aL9'
    },
    {
      'external_urls': {
        'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/2kPbQDZvnasPcCuXbq6YQx'
      },
      'followers': {
        'href': None,
        'total': 156
      },
      'genres': [

      ],
      'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/2kPbQDZvnasPcCuXbq6YQx',
      'id': '2kPbQDZvnasPcCuXbq6YQx',
      'images': [

      ],
      'name': 'Bret Michaels (Featuring Brad Arnold of 3 Doors Down, Chris Cagle, Mark Wills)',
      'popularity': 4,
      'type': 'artist',
      'uri': 'spotify:artist:2kPbQDZvnasPcCuXbq6YQx'
    }
  ],
  'limit': 20,
  'next': None,
  'offset': 0,
  'previous': None,
  'total': 4
 }
}
```

Comment: Added an answer. If you tell me what exactly you are trying to do with those names, I can update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm using Django to pass them to a template through a context dictionary, but I know how to do that already.  I'm still getting a KeyError when I run your code.

Comment: Can you post the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

```
artists = search_results['artists']['items'] # This is a list
for artist in artists: # artist is each object in the list
    print(artist['name'])
```

```
Output:
> '3 Doors Down'
> 'Bret Michaels (Featuring Brad Arnold of 3 Doors Down, Chris Cagle, Mark Wills)'
```